# How do I use GSON to convert an object array to an array of their IDs

Tags: android, json, gson

I've been using `Gson.toJson` to convert my object for a request:

```
class Convertable {

    private String[] mApples;
    private String[] mOranges;
    ...

}
```

Which gave me JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "apples": [
        "ahadhahajjajajaj",
        "afwqrbvlnwegoihw",
        "bnobnwoibbwwrbwb"
    ],
    "oranges": [
        "ahadhaha",
        "abvlnwew",
        "bnobrbwb"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Now my object has changed to

```
class Convertable {

    private String[] mApples;
    private MyChild[] mOranges;
    ...
}

class MyChild {

    private String mId; //is the string the json contained before
    ... //contains other fields the request doesnt need
}
```

But if it's possible I want to do something just as simple. How do I achieve this? Can it be done without writing a custom serializer and having to manually convert everything else in the object?

---

**Edit - More info:**

My current approach is as follows, I need to add and expose a method:

```
class Convertable {

    private String[] mApples;
    private transient MyChild[] mOranges;
    ...

    @SerializedName("oranges")
    public String[] getMyChildIds() {
        ...
    }

}
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way than this

Comment: put your MyChild class in Convertable and make ArrayList instead of Array of MyChild, then try to convert it to json by Gson. but it should be done by Array too but i used ArrayList and it had converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom converter for the `Convertable` class, just for the `MyChild`. And register it using `GsonBuilder#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`. That way you don't need to change anything about `Convertable`.

```
public class MyChildAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyChild> {
  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, MyChild myChild)
          throws IOException
  {
    out.value(myChild.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public MyChild read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    // implement it if needed
    return null;
  }
}
```